# C# Sql Server Save Point

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, powershell, azure-pipelines

I am trying to run an end-to-end test and would like the ability to roll back the environment each time I run the tests.  I am wondering if there is a way to create a savepoint at the beginning of the end-to-end test then roll all the db changes (no matter how it was made) back?  I'd like this to be all done in c# but if there is a way to do this in powershell or the like that may work as well.  All of this is needed to be implemented in an azure pipeline as well on a local test server.

Comment: You could make a backaup of the db and restore it afterwards. Have a look at SqlServer module of powershell.

Comment: Don't make backup.  It is better to deattach the mdf file from server and make copy of the mdf in windows.  The attach the copy of the mdf to the server.

Comment: set up a [docker](https://www.docker.com/)

Comment: If you can use docker the suggestion given above will be the best, since you can have your docker image with everything configured (SQL server) and your data set. You can create your own image for that !!

Comment: I don't want to go with docker our docker hosting is limited to 10GB when we create a docker image the image is over 30GB

Comment: Could you create a database with the same schema, load in whatever minimal test data you need for the tests and then delete it again? That way you don't have to wait for restores or anything like that.